# Is there a way to have a branch policy that based on partial success or success of specific stage on devops?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am learning azure devop's PR build and PR release. I setup the needed triggers and my branch policy is like this, so will pass if the PR release is successful.

[image]

Say in the PR release, we have several stages (testing stage, tear down testing environment stage and approve stage).

Think about this scenario:
The testing stage contains some automated tests and some tests failed. Then this stage will be marked as failure.  Our QA looked into it and believes the failed tests are very minor and shouldn't stop the pr from merged and deployed.  So they want to approve this PR.

However, as this stage failed and even if other stages are successful, the status of this release will not be "Succeeded". As a result, the PR can't continue. I simulated this by skipping a stage and you can see that if one stage is not successful, the PR will show "Check failed".
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to check a specific stage's status other than whole release's status?

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can accept the answer which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can get down to that level, there's nothing in the portal or the API to suggest that you can do this. As a workaround, you could do this:

1. change your build validation gate from Required to Optional - this will trigger the build, but not block on partial success.

[image: Optional Build Gate]

2. add a script step to the "Should Deploy" stage that uses the [PR Status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to post a status back to the PR.

[image: PR Status Update JSON]

3. add a status check policy to the branch to look for the status you posted in the previous step.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, end of the day, there is a very simple solution. If one of the stage or task failed, but our QA believe it is ok, he can just modify the release and comment out a couple of tasks and then do a redeploy. This will make the stage succeed and in turn the pr release will post succeed status.

Comment: That approach can work, we've certainly done things like that in the past. Just keep in mind that if you do this, it diminishes the audit trail of your implementation. If you do get audited on application development controls, people with be head-scratching at random release modifications.

Comment: thanks, I think your devop process is much more mature than our one. Also I didn't even realize that I can type a status in the "Status to check" box. I thought it was just a dropdown to select things. Now it makes sense. I could post a status back like "Boss said so"  and check that specific status!!